# Possible to call phone numbers from an Azure Function App in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App which sends emails and sms messages based on data received from an endpoint. Recently I've been asked to include phone calling for high priority issues. I haven't been able to find any resources or hints on how to handle this with using Azure resources.

Is this even possible with Azure resources? If not, can somebody point me in the right direction for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked into Twilio ?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat That seems to be the answer. I was hoping to have all expenses going through Azure, but it appears that I'll need to set up an account with Twilio now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it not possible with azure functions but you might want to look into azure communication services https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/telephony/pstn-call?pivots=platform-web :]

Comment: I looked into it earlier. Telephony seems to only work with web, ios, and android apps.

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote in comments you can use Twilio or Plivo. I am using both, one as backup, as in my case I am using it for sms mainly, and if messages was not delivered with one carrier i will retry with other. Both works with Azure function.

As for twilio you can even have a look into [AF binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-twilio?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp) but its only for sms.

Also other way of doing would using logic app. You could publish message to queue and then using connectors to do some stuff.
For instance [plivo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/plivo/) connector supports calls  but [twilio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/twilio/) only sms